# Where do I put [SuprressPropertyChangedWarnings] to suppress the build warning in WPF?

Tags: build, suppress-warnings, fody

I'm getting a build warning in the Output window of Visual Studio that states:

... warning : Fody/PropertyChanged: Unsupported signature for a On_PropertyName_Changed method: OnUsersChanged in MainWindowViewModel. You can suppress this warning with [SuppressPropertyChangedWarnings].

This is the method that is causing the error.

```
 private void OnUsersChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            defaultChangeFactory.Current.OnCollectionChanged(this, "Users",
               Users, e);
        }
```

My question is where to put [SuppressPropertyChangedWarnings] to suppress the warning?  I tried using [SuppressPropertyChangedWarnings] as an attribute to the method but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can either put it directly above the static OnPropertyChanged method, in your case right above OnUsersChanged like so:

```
[SuppressPropertyChangedWarnings]
private void OnUsersChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
```

or you can put it directly above your class declaration if you have many OnPropertyChanged methods like so:

```
[SuppressPropertyChangedWarnings]
public class MyClassGrid: Grid
{
...
}
```

Comment: Reza .. Thanks.  Using [SupressPropertyChangedWarnings] on each On...Changed() method worked just fine.